# What does logistic model assumption "The true conditional probabilities are a logistic function of the independent variables" mean?

Tags: logistic, assumptions

[Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/logistic/chapter3/statalog3.htm) a list of model assumptions for logistic regression is given.

Number 1 is:

> The true conditional probabilities are a logistic function of the independent variables.

What does this technically mean?

Comment: In practice, it means that the model fits the data well.

Comment: I don't get it, mavavilj. You have asked 98 questions here, but you've only accepted an answer 10 times & you've only upvoted 9 answers. If you think the information you get here isn't worthwhile, why do you keep coming back & asking more questions? If you think some of the information you've received has been helpful, would you consider upvoting & accepting the answers that have helped you?

Comment: @gung Yes I will go through them. I read them, but forget to pick the answer.

Comment: I glad to know they're helping you, @mavavilj.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that one of the assumptions of *linear* regression is linearity, which is expressed as

$$\mu_{y|x_1, \dots, x_k} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \dots + \beta_kx_k$$

The logistic regression assumption that you just stated may be interpreted in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways that $P(Y=1|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, ..., X_p=x_p)$ may operate.

Let's simplify by considering a single independent variable (single predictor), $x$. Then as $x$ increases, how does $P(Y=1)$ change?

Even if we restricted ourselves to monotonic nondecreasing functions there are many possible choices (essentially any cdf might be used).

The logistic corresponds to saying $P(Y=1) = [1+e^{-(\alpha+\beta x)}]^{-1}$ (though this can be written in several other forms), a family of relationships indexed by two parameters which change the position of the place where $P(Y=1) = \frac12$ and how steep the function is there (the scale).

[image]

The function in blue is the logistic. The function in green is a normal cdf, producing a "probit" rather than "logit" model; somewhat similar in shape but it turns more sharply near the top and bottom of the range. The remaining curve is a Weibull cdf. On the logit scale all the logistic functions would be linear but the other possibilities would not be linear on that scale.

To respond to the request in comments -- aside from the legend, something like the above plot can be produced by:

```
 x  <- (0:100)/10
 xx <- (x-5)/.8
 y  <- 1/(1+exp(-xx))
 plot(x,y,type="l",col=4,ylab="P(Y=1|X=x)")
 lines(x,pnorm((x-5)),col=3)
 lines(x,1-exp(-(x/5)^1.4),col=2)
 abline(h=c(0,1),col=8)
```

Comment: Beautiful graph. Would you share your code?